# how to use JQuery to insert after and append using draggable and droppable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm trying to build a Bootstrap editor. I have a `<li>` menu of supposed Bootstrap classes or tools, whatever. there is a difference between `<li>` to add a new section and `<li>` to add some tools. to add a section I use insert after and to add tool I use append. sections here are 'current' or 'new'.

**JQuery**

```
<script>
    $(function () {

        $(".draggable").draggable({
            helper: "clone",
            end: function (e, ui) {
                const Holded_ItemID = ui.draggable.attr("id");
                if (Holded_ItemID == 'Sec') {
                    $("li").removeClass("NewSection"); 
                    $(ui.helper).addClass("NewSection");
                }
            }
        });

        $("#droppable").droppable({
            drop: function (e, ui) {
                const Holded_ItemID = ui.draggable.attr("id");
                if (Holded_ItemID == 'Sec') {
                //to insert new section after current section
                $(this).children().last().insertAfter($(ui.draggable).clone());
                }
                else
                {
                //to add elemnt inside the new section
                    $('.NewSection').append($(ui.draggable).clone());
                };
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
    <ul>
        <li id="Sec" class="draggable">add new section</li>
        <li class="draggable ui-widget-content">add new grid</li>
        <li class="draggable ui-widget-content">add new button</li>
        <li class="draggable ui-widget-content">add new Image</li>
        <li class="draggable ui-widget-content">add new card</li>
        <li class="draggable ui-widget-content">add new media objects</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="droppable ui-widget-header">
      <p>Area Of web design</p>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
  <style>
  .draggable { width: 170px; height: 20px; border:1px dotted black; padding: 1px 1px 1px 10px; margin:3px; }
  .droppable { width: 500px; height: 300px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px; padding:10px; background-color:antiquewhite; }
  </style>
```

Simply, I can't add anything from the li menu into the droppable area. Why, what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few notes:

- for `draggable({})` you have to use [stop()](https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop) event not `end`.
- I used `ui.helper` to access the dragged element.
- insteadof `$(this).children().last().insertAfter` I used just append, not sure why you used that, so you might want to amend my change as you like.

I think this is what you want,

```js
$(function () {
  $(".draggable").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    stop: function (e, ui) {
      //console.log(ui.helper[0]);
      const Holded_ItemID = $(ui.helper[0]).attr("id");
      if (Holded_ItemID == 'Sec') {
        $("li").removeClass("NewSection"); 
        $(ui.helper[0]).addClass("NewSection");
      }
    }
  });

  $("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function (e, ui) {
      const Holded_ItemID = $(ui.draggable[0]).attr("id");
      if (Holded_ItemID == 'Sec') {
      //to insert new section after current section
        $("#droppable").append(ui.draggable[0])
        //$(this).children().last().insertAfter($(ui.draggable).clone());
      } else {
        //to add elemnt inside the new section
        $("#droppable").append($(ui.draggable[0]).clone());
      };
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.draggable { width: 170px; height: 20px; border:1px dotted black; padding: 1px 1px 1px 10px; margin:3px; }
.droppable { width: 500px; height: 300px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px; padding:10px; background-color:antiquewhite; }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li id="Sec" class="draggable">add new section</li>
    <li class="draggable ui-widget-content">add new grid</li>
    <li class="draggable ui-widget-content">add new button</li>
    <li class="draggable ui-widget-content">add new Image</li>
    <li class="draggable ui-widget-content">add new card</li>
    <li class="draggable ui-widget-content">add new media objects</li>
</ul>

<div id="droppable" class="droppable ui-widget-header">
  <p>Area Of web design</p>
</div>
```